# webpack+babel npm doesnt want to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

Super People of goodwill !! I am just a beginner of this amazing magic craft such as is programming :) And I have this kind of 
issue. Basically I know so web pack is telling me what is wrong but 
still, I can fix it :( 
here is my webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path') 
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
entry: [
'babel-polyfill',  
'./js/index.js',
'./js/nav.js'
'./scss/main.scss',
],
output: {
filename: 'index.js', 
libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
path: path.resolve('./dist/'),
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader']),
  },
  {
    test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-
 loader','babel-loader']),
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
    }
  }
 },


  ]
 },
 plugins: [
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  output: {
    comments: false
  }
 }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles.css',
  allChunks: true,
}),
]
}

my package.json :

{
"name": "simple-webpack-boilerplate",
"version": "0.0.1",
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
},
"babel": {
"presets": [
  "es2015"
 ]
 },
 "author": "Michał Grabowski (michal.grabowski@gmail.com)",
 "license": "MIT",
"description": "",
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
"css-loader": "0.28.7",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "^1.1.5",
"node-sass": "4.7.2",
"resolve-url-loader": "^2.2.1",
"sass-loader": "6.0.6",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2",
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
},
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.35",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.35",
"init": "^0.1.2"
}
 }
```

And finally, my errors on the terminal when I am trying to start my npm 
    :

```
`> simple-webpack-boilerplate@0.0.1 start 
/Users/Niemiec/Desktop/michal_web
> webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch

/Users/Niemiec/Desktop/michal_web/webpack.config.js:10
'./scss/main.scss',
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at requireConfig   
npm ERR! Failed at the simple-webpack-boilerplate@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Niemiec/.npm/_logs/2017-12-26T21_30_23_846Z-
debug.log
Krzysztofs-MacBook-Pro:michal_web Niemiec$ 

`
```

Help, please !!

Comment: why are you using 'babel-loader' on css files ?

Comment: do you have any other js code ?

Comment: syntax error in the entry point

Comment: basically i have nav.js i probablcy i will put few more..i am not so sure..about babel-loaderr i thought so its requier to have it if I wanna uses babel with my JS ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entry: [
'babel-polyfill',  
'./js/index.js',
'./js/nav.js'
'./scss/main.scss',
],
```

The comma is in the wrong place, you should move the `,` from `'./scss/main.scss'` one line above to `'./js/nav.js'`

Comment: ups..looks like i made more mess than i thought so.. :)

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./scss/main.scss
    Module build failed: Error: Multiple configuration files found. Please remove one:
    - .babelrc
    - package.json
but i cant fint a babelrc files..

Comment: .babelrc should be on your root directory, maybe you don't see it because it starts with a dot so it's hidden. Try running the command `ls -a` on the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a `,` in your `entry` list. Give this a try:

```
entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',  
    './js/index.js',
    './js/nav.js'
    './scss/main.scss',
],
```

Comment: ok i cn run a npm now, but...now...ehgg       its like that ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./scss/main.scss
    Module build failed: Error: Multiple configuration files found. Please remove one:
    - .babelrc
    - package.json
i probelm is..where i can find a babelrc files ?